# How to sum and group in one column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I created an example just for this question so don't look at the table itself.

I have this table ([see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12tHT.png)) which is filled automatically therefore I cannot change the columns.

I am trying to summarize the table with a query and save it in an another table. I need to group by the DepartmentName, Date and Turn and also create a "list" which shows me the sum of Nationalities depending on the Turn (For example: 5 EN, 5 US, 5 ES, 5 FR).

This should be the output (where Quantity is the total amount based on Turn and OtherNationalities is the list of nationalities based on Turn):

| DepartmentName | Date | Turn | Quantity | OtherNationalities |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Marketing | 2022-11-17 | Afternoon | 30 | 4 ES, 6 FR |
| Marketing | 2022-11-17 | Morning | 30 | 4 ES, 6 FR |
| Sales | 2022-11-17 | Afternoon | 20 | 5 EN, 5 US |
| Sales | 2022-11-17 | Morning | 20 | 5 EN, 5 US |
| Sales | 2022-11-17 | Night | 20 | 5 EN, 5 US |
| Sales | 2022-11-18 | Afternoon | 20 | 5 EN, 5 US |
| Sales | 2022-11-18 | Morning | 20 | 5 EN, 5 US |
| Sales | 2022-11-18 | Night | 20 | 5 EN, 5 US |

This is the code that I have done so far:

```
SELECT DepartmentName, Date, Turn,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN Turn = 'Morning' THEN MorningQuantity
        WHEN Turn = 'Afternoon' THEN AfternoonQuantity
        WHEN Turn = 'Night' THEN NightQuantity
    END) AS Quantity,
    CASE
        WHEN Turn = 'Morning' THEN STRING_AGG(CAST(MorningQuantity AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ' + Nationality, ', ')
        WHEN Turn = 'Afternoon' THEN STRING_AGG(CAST(AfternoonQuantity AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ' + Nationality, ', ')
        WHEN Turn = 'Night' THEN STRING_AGG(CAST(NightQuantity AS VARCHAR(3)) + ' ' + Nationality, ', ')
    END AS OtherNationalities
FROM DummyTable
GROUP BY DepartmentName, Date, Turn
```

And this is the output: [current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67pAZ.png).

It almost work but it can happen that the data comes with some duplicates (don't ask me why because I don't know...) but they have to be added to the Quantity and OtherNationalities columns.

I have no clue how to group and sum that column (OtherNationalities) in order to get "4 ES, 6 FR". I appreciate any kind of advice and help!

Answer (score 0):

A self join would be one idea:

```
SELECT DepartmentName, Date, Turn,
    SUM(CASE
        WHEN Turn = 'Morning' THEN MorningQuantity
        WHEN Turn = 'Afternoon' THEN AfternoonQuantity
        WHEN Turn = 'Night' THEN NightQuantity
    END) AS Quantity,
    q2.OtherNationalities
FROM 
    DummyTable d1
    cross appy
    (
        select OtherNationalities = string_agg(q1.Nationality,',')
        from 
            (
                select distinct Nationality
                from DummyTable d2
                where d2.DepartmentName=d1.DepartmentName and d2.Date=d1.Date and d2.Turn=d1.Turn
            )q1
    )q2
GROUP BY DepartmentName, Date, Turn, q2.OtherNationalities
```

Comment: Interesting, but how can you sum the quantity based on turn? Your output is just "ES, FR" but i need " 4 ES, 6 FR"

Comment: oh. well change the distinct in q1 to group by and ass the sum there

Comment: *ADD the sum there

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much, can you please edit your answer so I can accept it?